# Is it possible to override ActionScript's Stage.scaleMode property with the embed HTML tag?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript, embed, scale

I have an embed SWF file on my page. This Flash contains the following AS line :

```
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
```

I would like to override this settings with the default `showAll` scaling mode on the HTML page. The `embed` tag provide the `scale` attribute **but it just doesn't scale anything!** (I mean : a cropping occur when I reduce the size.)
Here's the code :

```
<embed
    src="my/flash/file.swf"
    scale="default" // I also tried "exactFit"
    quality="high"
    width="500"
    height="400"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
/>
```

I noticed **it works when I right-click the Flash object and check the "Show all"** entry of the Flash Player menu. This mean that the Flash object behavior can be overriden in some way.

Why isn't the `scale` attribute working as expected ? Am I missing something ? Is it forbidden to override this hard-coded property in HTML ?

Thank you !

*Edit : here are the two references for the AS `scaleMode` property and the `embed` attribute :*

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001543.html
- http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Im sure you can, as you can change the perimeters of the flash movie from outside of it, i wouldnt see why it wont work, theres away..

from experience i once read you couldnt overlap several flash movies on a page and also have a swf as a background, eventually i had achieved this using php and css proberly a fluke but eventually i had 5 swf on top of each including a swf bg 1920x1080  on the same page...

just to add put your whole embedding code here, if it is not properly structured it wouldnt work anyways..

sorry about spelling i read into this tomorrow it 5 am here.